# RecursiveRegexIterator can not match Multidimensional Arrays

Tags: spl

```
<?php
$arr = array('a','ab','cd',array('ef','ad',array('cd','ae')));
$arrayIterator = new RecursiveArrayIterator($arr);

$it = new RecursiveRegexIterator($arrayIterator,'/^a\w*/',RecursiveRegexIterator::MATCH);

$recursiveIterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($it,RecursiveIteratorIterator::LEAVES_ONLY);

print_r(iterator_to_array($recursiveIterator,false));

?>
```

i want to get all strings which beginning with the letter 'a',
but it can not match the strings in 2D,3D...

Comment: Your code snippet seems to be working when I check it. What is the output you are expecting, and what is the actual output you are getting?

Comment: it just outputs Array ( [0] => a [1] => ab ) ,but i expect Array ( [0] => a [1] => ab [2] => ad [3] => ae )

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems to be affected by a SPL bug (https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=68128) that is solved in PHP 5.5.19.

Take a look at the example at: https://3v4l.org/6H2oI

Your best bet is to upgrade your PHP version to the latest php 5.5 version (note that this version is not supported anymore and upgrade to php 5.6 is recommended)